# Remix: Stay on the same page after form submit

Tags: remix.run

The official docs seem to reference a `redirect` function in the form action. This is fine if you're building a CMS, but what is the best way to simply refresh the current page with some save state (good or bad)?

Answer (score 2):

Posting a form in Remix is very close to Posting a form to a classic web server. Unless you specify a different URL in the `action` attribute of your `<form>`, it will post to the current route, execute the `action()` and re-render the route. This is a navigation event and will be reflected in the navigation history. If you were to POST to a different route, Remix would navigate to the new route and render the relevant component. The client-side routing enabled by Remix is a progressive enhancement, but all of this would work with js disabled as well.

This mechanism can be used to refresh the page, as [remix will automatically re-run all the loaders of the current matching routes](https://remix.run/docs/en/1.16.0/components/form#form) when processing an action, similar to a classic POST

However, If you simply want to refresh the data, the latest version of Remix provides [useRevalidators](https://remix.run/docs/en/main/hooks/use-revalidator) precisely to cover this use case.

If you want more details on why this API was chosen, this is discussed in the following issue: https://github.com/remix-run/remix/discussions/1996

Comment: So without getting too distracted by long-winded documentation, if that's true, is it generally taboo to have more than one form on a page? Seems unrealistic in the world of SPAs.

Comment: Great question. For now, you'd have to handle this yourself. You have two options: 
 1. Send a hidden "type" field and use a switch case statement to apply the correct processing depending on the type.
 2. Call a different route with an action that redirect back to the original page.

Remix actually addresses this in their FAQ [How do I handle multiple forms in one route](https://remix.run/docs/en/main/pages/faq#how-do-i-handle-multiple-forms-in-one-route). 

Keep in mind that remix isn't really an SPA, but more of an MPA that uses react for rendering and client-side navigation :)